# DT: format* overwrites columndefs

Tags: r, dt

I want to specify a certain column via columnDefs and then format the same column by format*. In this case I add a hover text over column *B* (column 2) and would like to color and round it later.
When adding `formatStyle` to the datatable I still see the hover text, but other format functions such as `formatRound` seem to overwrite the columnDefs.

Is there a way to format a column using both columnDefs **and** format* in R without too much JS?

Here a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

data <- tibble(A = c("A", "AB"), B = c(-1, 1))

js <- c(
  "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
  "return type === 'display' ?",
  "'<span title=\"' + 'A: ' + row[1] + '\">' + data: data;",
  "}"
)

dt <- DT::datatable(
  data,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(
        targets = 1,
        visible = FALSE
      ),
      list(
        targets = 2,
        render = JS(js)
      )
    )
  )
)
# hover still works
dt %>%
  formatStyle(columns = "B", color = styleInterval(0, c("red", "green")))

# hover doesn't work anymore
dt %>%
  formatRound(columns = "B")
dt %>%
  formatSignif(columns = "B")
```

Comment: It's easy to add a rounding in your JS code. That's not "too much" JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it in JS is not "too much". For example, to round to 2 decimal digits:

```r
js <- c(
  "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
  "  return type === 'display' ?",
  "    '<span title=\"' + 'A: ' + row[1] + '\">' +", 
  "      Math.round(100*data)/100 : data;",
  "}"
)
```

Replace `100` with `1000` to round up to 3 digits, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I guess you're right. I just thought it's not a nice (eventhough intended as in their source code) feature of DT and there's workaround with DT itself.

Comment: @emrichter I think `formatRound` uses the `render` option.

Comment: yes it does via `render` and `JS`